# How to post a list to Advanced Rest Client

Tags: java, list, rest, service, client

My service code:

```
public RestResponse deleteEvents(@RequestBody List<RecordDto> delete, @RequestBody List<RecordDto> update)
```

and here is my RecordDto parameters:

```
private long uid;

private int type;

private String identification;

private String target;

private String reason;

private boolean edited;

private boolean deleted;
```

I use `application/json` as "Content-Type"
I am just trying to get 200 OK message. So values are not important for now.
What should I write to raw on Advanced Rest Client (Google Chrome Application)?

**I edited my codes like;**

```
public RestResponse updating(@RequestBody Update Update)
```

and here is Update:

```
private List<RecordDto> delete;
private List<RecordDto> update;
```

RecordDto:

```
private long uid;
private String ip;
private String cidr;
private String accesRule;
private boolean enabled;
private String createDate;
```

I am trying on Rest Client:

```
 {"delete":["uid":"", "ip":"" "cidr":"", "accesRule":"", "enabled":"", "createDate":""], 
  "update":["uid":"", "ip":"" "cidr":"", "accesRule":"", "enabled":"", "createDate":""]}
```

I use empty values for other rest services and they work fine. but  I do not know why this one is not working.

Comment: You can create json by hands or try to use Jackson library. Example you can take from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Why is @RequestBody twice in the method signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer :) here it is:

```
{
    "delete": [
        {
            "uid": "",
            "ip": "",
            "cidr": "",
            "accesRule": "",
            "enabled": "",
            "createDate": ""
        }
    ],
    "update": [
        {
            "uid": "",
            "ip": "",
            "cidr": "",
            "accesRule": "",
            "enabled": "",
            "createDate": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know how to test it from a testing client and what the data must look like.

It's an array of objects you need to Post

```
[
    {
        "uid": 243,
        "type": 1,
        "identification": "some string",
        "target": "more strings",
        "reason": "reason",
        "edited": false,
        "deleted" false
    },
    {
        "uid": 243,
        "type": 1,
        "identification": "some string",
        "target": "more strings",
        "reason": "reason",
        "edited": false,
        "deleted" false
    }
]
```

Comment: I use "" (empty) as value for every parameters and still get 400 Bad Request

Comment: you can't user "" for boolean and numeric parameters